# Why does a form move trigger ResizeEnd?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resize, window-resize

I use the following code in my form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ResizeEnd
        MsgBox("Resized")
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I move my form, it also seems to trigger `MyBase.ResizeEnd`. Why is that? A move of the panel doesn't change the size, so I don't understand why.

Comment: Why does it do that? Because this is [the documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks): _"The ResizeEnd event is also generated after the user moves a form, typically by clicking and dragging on the caption bar."_. Why did the Microsoft developers make that decision? We don't know. Use the `Resize` or `SizeChanged` event instead. You could use a `Boolean` variable to wait for the resize to end. See an example for C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404977/8967612).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help!
I tried to use the boolean variable through a c# to VB converter, but I don't know how to get it working. I also tried to find VB examples on the internet, but for some reason I'm unable to find any. Strange, I have a hard time believing I'm the first one that wants to implement a resize-only event??
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've posted an answer with a complete example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does a form move trigger ResizeEnd?

Because this is the documented behavior. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks):

> The ResizeEnd event is also generated after the user moves a form, typically by clicking and dragging on the caption bar.

If you want an event that doesn't get triggered when the form is moved, you should use either `Resize` or `SizeChanged`. The problem with those two events is that they will be triggered *while the form is being resized* by the user. To work around that, you may use it with both `ResizeBegin` and `ResizeEnd` with a couple of flags to signal when the user actually finishes resizing the form.

Here's a complete example:

```
Private _resizeBegin As Boolean
Private _sizeChanged As Boolean

Private Sub Form1_ResizeBegin(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ResizeBegin
    _resizeBegin = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.SizeChanged
    ' This is to avoid registering this as a resize event if it was triggered
    ' by another action (e.g., when the form is first initialized).
    If Not _resizeBegin Then Exit Sub

    _sizeChanged = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ResizeEnd
    _resizeBegin = False
    If _sizeChanged Then
        _sizeChanged = False
        MessageBox.Show("The form has been resized.")
    End If
End Sub
```

One thing to note is that both `ResizeBegin` and `ResizeEnd` are only triggered when the user *manually* resizes<sup>*</sup> the form. It does *not*, however, handle other situations like when the form is resized via code, when the form is maximized, or restored.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>or moves the form, which is the part that we're trying to avoid here.</sub>

Comment: Hi @41686d6564 stands w. Palestine,
This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you **VERY** much!
Kind regards,
Eric